# Facebook Suddenly Not Showing og:image?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Seems like FB has an issue fetching or displaying properly set og:image on our links suddenly - this affects share dialogs etc.

Everything has been working fine so far. I noticed this issue today.

Debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ shows the image after refetching (try: http://cakesdecor.com/cakes/194565-3d-vintage-clock-cake) but the image doesn't appear in the share dialog at all.

Is it a temporary bug or are there some new FB policies re images?

Comment: I see that most of the other urls are working fine in share dialog.. might be this particular URL would be having some issues like this `"Attempted Frozen Title Change"` it was showing when i scraped for that URL. try resolving it

Comment: All new URLs have this same issue. Old are fine because those are cached.

Comment: try resolving this error `"Attempted Frozen Title Change"`. I see most of the new URL's have the same error shown in debugger.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a Facebook bug report and as such is outside the scope of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Approx. 2 hours ago, this bug was confirmed by FB!

see: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978421888869140/

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this issue also occurs on multiple sites I own. It began some time in the past 14 hours. The debugger is returning a valid output (but the post preview at the bottom is lacking the image).

My guess is that it is somehow related to the face that today (30/apr) they've forced all fb apps to migrate to sdk2.0.

I sure hope they're already working on a fix... but go figure :-/